# Generate a unique string

Tags: php, objective-c, math

I found this answer in another post, on how to generate a random number:

```
-(NSString *) genRandStringLength:(int)length 
 {
  NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";


NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    [randomString appendFormat: @"%c", [letters characterAtIndex: rand()%[letters     length]]];
}

return randomString;
 }
```

I building a game and need to generate a unique id for each match. If I have 100,000 new matches a day (when a game is done, it's deleted and its unique id can be reused), what would be safe length to use in the code above, to make sure there won't be any conflicts (2 matches with the same id)? Or is there a better way to generate a unique id?

I want to try to keep the length down for performance, since it will be sent back and forth to the server.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a hash of the player names in the match?

Comment: Yes... although, one player (name) can have several matches running. And other players need to be able to get the unique id. The game is running on the iphone, and information is send to php, and put on a mysql server.

Comment: BIG WARNING: Consecutive calls of rand() will always return the same sequence of numbers unless you seed it with a random number using srand(). Better use random() or arc4random() instead of rand()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), this should be a globally unique across the world (within reason - certainly fine for you situation as chances of collision are incredibly low).

An Objective-C example can be found [here](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/09/creating-guid-or-uuid-in-objective-c.html).